# Lotus Notes, How can I view who has accepted by meeting invitation?

Tags: lotus-notes, meeting-request

When I schedule a meeting in Lotus Notes,and someone accepts I get an acceptance notification. Short of saving all those, is there any way to view who has or has not accepted the invitation

Answer (score 0):

If you do not delete these responses (I personally put them in a special folder), then you can open the meeting and in the Action bar you will find "Owner Actions" and there the possibility to check the status of the invitees. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/cs-pt1/) you find a good description of the whole process and in the section Invitee status the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply ***right click*** the calendar event and select ***show status of invited persons*** (or similar) to see a list of all invitees and their reaction.
(At least in IBM Notes v9.0.1, but I believe this feature was present in previous versions, too.)

You can then switch between *All invitees*, *Accepted only*, *Rejected only* or *No answer* at the top of the status window.

#### Note

> In my experience, for this feature to work, you **don't have to keep the reply messages** - I delete mine immediately and still see correct information in the calendar event.